# What's the size of EOS block header? and How is the "420 MB/ year" data derived?

Tags: block-header

I read the technical whitepaper and want to know estimate the total size of block header in a year. Thanks , it's important for me  " Tracking all block headers (420 MB/year) will keep proof sizes small"
https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md

Answer (score 2):

**Updated (11/30/2020)**

In original post, I calculated the size of extensions_type (header_extensions) field as 4 bytes, but it is an alias name of `std::vector<std::pair<uint16_t,std::vector<char>>>`, and it is serialized to 1 byte when it has no elements. Thus, the size of block header will be 116 bytes instead of 119 bytes. (I updated original post below)

**Original**

I'm not sure on which version of code technical whitepaper is based, but it's a little different from my calculation.

```
namespace eosio { namespace chain {

struct block_header
{
   block_timestamp_type              timestamp; // 4
   account_name                      producer; // 8
   uint16_t                          confirmed; // 2
   block_id_type                     previous; // 32
   checksum256_type                  transaction_mroot; // 32
   checksum256_type                  action_mroot; // 32
   uint32_t                          schedule_version; // 4
   optional<producer_schedule_type>  new_producers; // 1 
   extensions_type                   header_extensions; // 1
};

} }
```

Each block header consumes 116 bytes and 63,072,000 blocks are generated every year. (2 blocks/sec * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365) Roughly, `6977.4170 MiB/year` is necessary to store all block headers. (It would be larger, because the size of `new_producers` and `header_extension` grow when they aren't empty)

Comment: thanks, i also think 7157.8674 MiB/year is the correct result, and it's important because the storage cost can be large different based the data above.